# JS Count Title Length

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to count the title length using js and for some reason its not working. Here is the code that tries to get the title length * 45

```
$cnt = document.title.length * 45;
```

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Jan

Comment: You're going to provide much more code including the html to begin with.

Comment: More code is required. Does your html contains a title?

Comment: @SatejS Is that a jedi mind trick? But no, you're right. ;)

Comment: Yes it has the title in the header section. <title>10 Ways to Stay Positive</title>

Comment: If you are using jQuery: `$('title').html().length();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use JQuery Then below code find title length :

```js
 $($(document).find("title")[0]).text().length;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check to see if it is defined before you check the length:

```
function documentTitleLength() {
    var len = 0;
    if (typeof(document)!="undefined") {
        if (typeof(document['title'])!="undefined") {
            len = document['title'].toString().length;
        }
    }
    return len;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this.. this should work.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerText.length;
```